# WP7 Textbox in UserControl isn't bringing up keyboard

Tags: windows-phone-7, user-controls, textbox

So I'm testing a few things out with Windows Phone 7 and I'm having this really weird bug where a textbox inside a UserControl doesn't bring up the SIP when I set it as the focus. Outside the UserControl on the MainPage, textboxes work just fine and selecting it brings up the keyboard but when the textbox is inside the usercontrol, nothing. I've even tried to workaround it by setting the MouseLeftButtonDown event on textbox call a method that calls Focus() on the textbox directly and still nothing. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug with WP7 emulator?

XAML Code for the control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WindowsPhoneClient.SearchPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit" 
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="696" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WindowsPhoneClient">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TextBox></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Are you sure the TextBox isn't being covered up by any other control, and giving the illusion it isn't working? Posting your XAML might help.

Comment: Works fine for me. What does the page you're hosting the control in look like? Maybe there's a clue there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem, on my main page I was trying to use

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SearchPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

But SearchPage was a UserControl and not a PhoneApplicationPage so that was the problem. I wasn't aware that a Page and a UserControl were different, silly me. >_<